# Numbers Comparison - Python Bug?

Tags: python, numbers

Deep inside my code, in a nested if inside a nested for inside a class method, I'm comparing a certain index value to the length of a certain list, to validate I can access that index. The code looks something like that:

```
if t.index_value < len(work_list):
    ... do stuff ...
else:
    ... print some error ...
```

For clarification, `index_value` is at least zero (validated somewhere else). To my surprise, even though I know the `index_value` data is valid, the code keeps going to the "else:" clause. I added some ad-hoc debug code:

```
print('Checking whether '+str(t.index_value)+"<"+str(len(work_list)))

x = t.index_value
y = len(work_list)

print(x)
print(y)
print(x<y)

if t.index_value < len(work_list):
    ... do stuff ...
else:
    ... print some error ...
```

Following is the output:

```
>> Checking whether 3<4
>> 3
>> 4
>> False
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Further clarifications:

- work_list is a local variable instantiated within the method
- t is a class instance, instantiated within the method ( `t = SomeClass()` )

---

Update: The problem was that the type of `t.index_value` was UNICODE and not int. The reason was that I deserialized the contents of t from a text file, where the value of index_value is represented by a single digit character. After I extracted it from the text, I immediately assigned it to `index_value`, without passing it through int() which it what I should have done, and that solved the problem.

I decided to keep the "controversial" title despite the fact it's clearly my bug and not Python's, because people with the same problem may find it using this title.

Comment: Could you add a line under your first print statement? Try print(type(t.index_value))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, what is the type of "t.index_value"? Maybe it is a string "3".

```
>>> print '3' < 4
False
```

Answer (score 2):

To display values which might be of different types than you expect (e.g. a string rather than a number, as kcwu suggests), use `repr(x)` and the like.